# rendering reportviewer as PDf affects the display

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportviewer, reporting-services, reportviewer2008

After performing "serverreport.render" in order to print the report in PDF format, the Interactive sort does not work on the WebPage.

Below is my code.

```
private void Print()
{
    HttpContext cont = HttpContext.Current;
    HttpResponse myRes = cont.Response;
    System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState mySess = cont.Session;

    string enCoding = null;
    string strNull = null;
    string strPDF = "PDF";
    enCoding = Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
    string mimeType = "application/pdf";
    string extension = ".pdf";
    string[] streamids = null;
    Warning[] warnings = null;

    byte[] mybytes = null;

    mybytes = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render(strPDF, strNull, out mimeType, 
            out enCoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

    myRes.Buffer = true;
    myRes.Clear();
    myRes.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    myRes.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=output.pdf");
    myRes.BinaryWrite(mybytes);
    myRes.Flush();
    myRes.End();

}
```

Apparently the rendering of the report as PDF messes up things.

All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

If you require interactive sorting to be available on the web interface, you'll need to display the report via the Report Viewer or HTML (but not MHTML).

Once a report has been rendered to anything other than Report Viewer or HTML, Interactive Sorting is not available.

[Comparing Interactive Functionality for Different Report Rendering Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345232%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)